# Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise Add Unit Test project throws Package Installation Error

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, visual-studio-2017

I have a solution with projects pointing to .Net Framework 4.5 which I have opened in Visual Studio 2017 and tried to Unit Test Project pointing to .Net Framework 4.5. I am getting the following error

Package Installation error .

Could not add all required packages to the project. The following packages failed to install from 'C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Extensions\502SXCIF.E5I\Packages':

MSTest.TestFramework.1.1.11: Failed to add reference to 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework'

I have tried changing the Platform to x86 as suggested on some online resources.

I am using a Windows 7 Enterprise 64 bit. Has anyone been able to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

MsUnit test related template got missed in your local system.if you have another version please try to copy respective folder it will resolve the issue.

Comment: Thanks Ravi. The referred packages are there at the mentioned location. It was a matter of dirty install. I had to repair and restart twice. The installation fails for some reason and does not give enough information. Just says restart and it will continue installation but that did not happen either so I had to repair it twice. Like old Microsoft days :). The key is to keep repairing it till it installs and says "Successfully Installed"